# Prove/Disprove that the series is converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following series -

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty {\frac{\sin(1/n)}{\ln(n)}}$$

Well , I tried some of the tests for series but didn't succeed to get to the answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$\sin(\frac{1}{n})\sim\frac{1}{n}$ as $n\to\infty$. Does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ converge or diverge?

Comment: diverge because it it positive and monotonic decreasing , so my series is bigger than this series and therefore diverge? Can u write the comparison between the two series and explain ?

Comment: You can use the limit comparison test to compare $\sum_n\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\ln(n)}$ to $\sum_n\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$, then the integral test to show that $\sum_n\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ diverges.

Comment: Still i dont fully understand the comparison between those series,. Does the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ is bigger then $\sum_{n=2}^\infty {\frac{\sin(1/n)}{\ln(n)}}$  and why?

Comment: Look up the limit comparison test: since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}}=1$, the series $\sum_n\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}}{\ln(n)}$ and $\sum_n\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ either both converge or both diverge.

Comment: Got the idea.. thanks :)